# jQuery - show one instance of repeated div on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get a similar functionality to this website; http://theadeleexperience.com/ where you hover over the thumbnail, it shows the date of the post. I have all of the PHP and HTML code in place, but i need some help with my jQuery code to get this working.

The code below will show (obviously) every instance of the .test div when hovered (ironically, except the one i hover over); however i only want it to show the .test div i'm hovering - not the other 3 instances of it.

There may be an easier way to implement this other than the code below, or even without using jQuery for that matter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".test").hide();
    $(".thumbnail").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".test").show();
    $(".thumbnail").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".test").hide();
    });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img alt="thumbnail here" src="http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/87fb9072abad11e2b60722000a9f09f0_7.jpg" />
    <div class="test">here is a test content</div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').hide();
    $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.test').each(function(e){
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
    $('.thumbnail').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.test').each(function(e){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
.thumbnail {
    width:200px;
}
.thumbnail img{
    width:100%;
}
.test{
    background: black;
    color: white;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Seems like a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/29E4j/3/) is the solution I came up with.

The main problem with the code that you provided was that you didn't close off your brackets after the `mouseenter` function. The key to getting only the one you are hovering on is by using `this`. You can give an argument to `this`, as seen below. `.overlay`, is what is being targeted, but you use `this` to ensure it is only the one being hovered over. The final code should look like this

```
$(".overlay").hide();
$("article").on("hover", function () {
  $(".overlay", this).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").hide();
    $(".test").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".test").show();
    });
    $(".test").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".test").hide();
    });
});
```

You focus on the test not on the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("article").hover(function() {
    $(".overlay", this).slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(".overlay", this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: @CodyGuldner does it have any overhead? never heard about it

Comment: It isn't a noticeable difference, but if you look at the jquery source, it links back to the `.on("hover")` method

Comment: @CodyGuldner if you lookk at the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) it says  `.hover()`  is a shorthadnd for `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

Comment: Just updated the code form jquery regd hover, it is as good as mouseover and mouseleave. I couldnt see anything that affects performance though.